# Why objects property value comparison does not check for nothing

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framwork and have an Entity Customer with a property of:

> CustomerStatus(possible values NULL, 0, 1)

I had code that read

```
If Not Customer.CustomerStatus = 1 Then
 ' I want this to execute when Customer.CustomerStatus Is NULL or 0
 'Do This
End If
```

However I noticed that this code does not get executed when Customer.CustomerStatus Is Nothing.

Is this correct for all objects or am I doing soemthing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomerStatus` is a `Nullable(int)`. This means it can be `NULL` (it doesn't have a value) or it can be any other `Int`.

Comparing `NULL` to `1` returns false. If you want the test to pass one `NULL` and `1` you could use `Customer.CustomerStatus = 1 Or (Not Customer.CustomerStatus.HasValue)`

Comment: Actually I need the test to pass a 0 or NULL and not the 1. I guess I can use Customer.CustomerStatus = 0 Or (Not Customer.CustomerStatus.HasValue) OR I could use Customer.CustomerStatus = 1 Or Customer.CustomerStatus Is Nothing. Is there a reason to choose one of these over the other?